# graph-tool graphviz_draw: how to set vertex height and width

Tags: python, graphviz, graph-tool

I'd like to set different heights and widths for the vertices.
It's easy with graph_draw:

```
graph_draw(DG, ...
        vertex_aspect=1.6,
        ...
        )
```

But vertex_aspect doesn't exist for graphviz_draw and setting height and width has no effect. It only draws circles not ovals.

```
graphviz_draw(DG, ...
        vprops={"height": 2, "width": 5},
        ...
        )
```

Thanks a lot for help

Comment: have you tried the argument `vsize`?

Comment: yes, vsize takes one value for both (height and width)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the shape to "oval" (the default is "circle"):

```
graphviz_draw(g, vprops={"height": 2, "width": 5, "shape": "oval"})
```

Comment: You should "accept" an answer, whenever you feel it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the node height and width as follows:

```
digraph {
node [height=2.0]
node [width=3.0]
A->B
node [height=1.0]
node [width=0.5]
c->d
}
```

[image]
Different aspect ratios as you change the width and heights according to your wishes, evaluated from top to bottom.

Now I realize this is straight `dot` syntax, but perhaps you can do the same effect?  In other words, with a particular aspect ratio in mind, like 1.5 for example, set `width = height * 1.5` and then use the syntax you mentioned above.

Comment: thanks, yes I tried the same effect with vprops={"height": 2, "width": 5} but this doesn't work

Comment: Alas! Yes I've had similar issues.  Always had the best luck making my program (usually C# or a domain-specific language of my own design) actually emit the `dot` syntax and then call the `dot` engine to produce the graph.  Got to the point that's how I use it now.